# XGBoost for multilabel classification?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost, multilabel-classification

Is it possible to use XGBoost for multi-label classification? Now I use `OneVsRestClassifier` over `GradientBoostingClassifier` from `sklearn`. It works, but use only one core from my CPU. In my data I have ~45 features and the task is to predict about 20 columns with binary (boolean) data. Metric is mean average precision (map@7). If you have a short example of code to share, that would be great.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? Please provide a solution if so.

Answer (score 20):

One possible approach, instead of using `OneVsRestClassifier` which is for multi-class tasks, is to use `MultiOutputClassifier` from the `sklearn.multioutput` module.

Below is a small reproducible sample code with the number of input features and target outputs requested by the OP

```
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.datasets import make_multilabel_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

# create sample dataset
X, y = make_multilabel_classification(n_samples=3000, n_features=45, n_classes=20, n_labels=1,
                                      allow_unlabeled=False, random_state=42)

# split dataset into training and test set
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=123)

# create XGBoost instance with default hyper-parameters
xgb_estimator = xgb.XGBClassifier(objective='binary:logistic')

# create MultiOutputClassifier instance with XGBoost model inside
multilabel_model = MultiOutputClassifier(xgb_estimator)

# fit the model
multilabel_model.fit(X_train, y_train)

# evaluate on test data
print('Accuracy on test data: {:.1f}%'.format(accuracy_score(y_test, multilabel_model.predict(X_test))*100))
```

Comment: Sir, what if the data feeding to the XGBoost model contains missing values?Though I knew xgboost works well with binary classification even the data contains missing values, but a preliminary try shows that it does not work with multilabel classifiction, when the data contains missing values.

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot help you specifically. However, I suggest you to impute missing values before training the model

Comment: wow this is so cool, I had no idea sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputClassifier exists and can wrap an arbitrary classifier like XGBoost. That's so helpful.

Answer (score 9):

There are a couple of ways to do that, one of which is the one you already suggested:

1.

```
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
# If you want to avoid the OneVsRestClassifier magic switch
# from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputClassifier

clf_multilabel = OneVsRestClassifier(XGBClassifier(**params))
```

`clf_multilabel` will fit one binary classifier per class, and it will use however many cores you specify in `params` (fyi, you can also specify `n_jobs` in `OneVsRestClassifier`, but that eats up more memory).

2.
If you first massage your data a little by making `k` copies of every data point that has `k` correct labels, you can hack your way to a simpler multiclass problem. At that point, just

```
clf = XGBClassifier(**params)
clf.fit(train_data)
pred_proba = clf.predict_proba(test_data)
```

to get classification margins/probabilities for each class and decide what threshold you want for predicting a label.
Note that this solution is not exact: if a product has tags `(1, 2, 3)`, you artificially introduce two negative samples for each class.

Comment: It should be noted that this can be very expensive to train if you have many labels, as it trains one model per label. I'm using `xgboost.XGBClassifier` as the underlying classifier and training using 5-fold cross validation takes hours.

@marco_ccc Thanks for this, it was very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You can add a label to each class you want to predict.
For example if this is your data:

```
X1 X2 X3 X4  Y1 Y2 Y3
 1  3  4  6   7  8  9
 2  5  5  5   5  3  2
```

You can simply reshape your data by adding a label to the input, according to the output, and `xgboost` should learn how to treat it accordingly, like so:

```
X1 X2 X3 X4 X_label Y
 1  3  4  6   1     7
 2  5  5  5   1     5
 1  3  4  6   2     8
 2  5  5  5   2     3
 1  3  4  6   3     9
 2  5  5  5   3     2
```

This way you will have a 1-dimensional `Y`, but you can still predict many labels.

Comment: Is the idea here that during test time, you would create a duplicate of each input row, changing the X_lable field and take that prediction as the label corresponding to X_label?

Answer (score 0):

per  [xgboost docs](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/multioutput.html), by default xgboost will fit one model per output, so just do:

```
clf = xgb.XGBClassifier(tree_method="hist")
clf.fit(X, y)
np.testing.assert_allclose(clf.predict(X), y)
```